# "build.js does not exist" after upgrading to Play 2.3 (requireJsShim)

Tags: scala, playframework, requirejs, playframework-2.3

I have a project using Play 2.2 and am attempting to upgrade it to Play 2.3.

As part of the build process, we used a custom RequireJS config file "build.js" imported using the option "requireJsShim" in our Build.scala file.

```
val myProject = Project("MyProject" ....).settings(
    requireJsShim += "build.js"
)
```

This correctly used the configuration file "/app/assets/javascripts/build.js for the RequireJS compilation stage.

However after upgrading to Play 2.3, I'm getting the following error

```
/target/scala-2.10/classes/public/javascripts/build.js does not exist
```

It appears requireJsShim is looking for the file here, however the new SbtWeb build pipeline is instead placing it here

```
/skedulo/target/web/rjs/build/javascripts/build.js
```

The requireJsShim option no longer appears to be a documented configuration parameter, and the new options as part of the RJS pipeline don't seem to cover the same use-case. Is there a way of having requireJsSim support in Play 2.3?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `requireJsShim` use `RjsKeys.mainConfig := "build"`

Also check my answer to a similar question. I've put more information there:
[Play 2.3 requireJs optimization and shim for multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420373/play-2-3-requirejs-optimization-and-shim-for-multiple-modules#answer-24578855)