# Play 2.3 requireJs optimization and shim for multiple modules

Tags: playframework-2.3, requirejs-optimizer, sbt-web

This is my current setup for Play 2.2.x requireJS. Will it continue to work after 2.3? I can't find requireJs or requireJsShim anywhere in the 2.3 documentation.

```
  requireJs ++= Seq("mainAccount.js", "mainOrg.js", "mainPublic.js"), // This tells Play to optimize this file and its dependencies
  requireJsShim += "build.js", // This tells Play to read the RequireJS "shim" configuration from build.js
  requireJsFolder := "js"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Instead of `requireJs` use:

   ```
   RjsKeys.modules := Seq(
       WebJs.JS.Object("name" -> "mainAccount"),
       WebJs.JS.Object("name" -> "mainOrg"),
       WebJs.JS.Object("name" -> "mainPublic")
   )
   ```
2. Instead of `requireJsShim` use
   `RjsKeys.mainConfig := "build"`
3. I think you can just omit `requireJsFolder` as `baseUrl` is considered to be either `js` or `javascripts` by default. See here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-rjs/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/rjs/SbtRjs.scala#L104
   If you want to change to something else, then use `RjsKeys.baseUrl := "your-js-dir-name"`

Also there is a github project using RequireJS that was migrated to Play 2.3, may be useful as well:
https://github.com/mariussoutier/play-angular-require-seed

For more details check sbt-rjs plugin docs:
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-rjs